# Delete multiple records together in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that I send a string param into it with this structure `10,11,12`.

And I want to split it with comma (`,`) and delete records in the table that contains these ids.

My procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteDeal]
    @orderIds varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM deal 
    WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT OrderId 
                      FROM STRING_SPLIT(@orderIds, ','));
END
```

But this code deletes all rows from the `deal` table.

How can I do this action?

Comment: Much better to send IDs in using a table valued parameter. Anyway, just debug your code outside of a SP, and change the delete to a select while you are debugging.

Comment: good idea, I will try with send table param

Comment: similar questions asked multiple times on SO

Comment: when you select from a STRING_SPLIT you have to query for the column `value` in stead of OrderID. As it stands your query will result in an exception `Invalid column name 'OrderId'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By suggestion, I create a table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[deleteDealType] AS TABLE(
    [OrderId] [bigint] 
)
```

and then change my procedure to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteDeal]
    @orderIds deleteDealType readonly
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM deal WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT OrderId FROM @orderIds);
END
```

and works perfectly